# Array within an array and using that data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dynamic, ionic3

Sorry if it's confusing, this is my first ionic project. So I have an array of data (The stuff above the line is the home page and beneath is the first sub page)

```js
this.cities = [
        {
          name: 'Miami',
          shortName: 'Mi',
          events: '12',
          news: '15',
          weather: '29',
          crimeAlert: 'n',
          crimeAlertTitle: '',
          crimeAlertBody: '',
          newsItems: [{
            name: 'someNewsItem 1',
            imaged: 'y',
            image: 'im here',
            body: 'Miami someBody 1'
          },{
            name: 'someNewsItem 2',
            imaged: 'y',
            image: 'im here',
            body: 'Miami someBody 2'
          }],
          eventItems: [{
            name: 'someEventItem 1',
            imaged: 'y',
            image: 'im here',
            body: 'Miami someBodyEvent 1'
          }]
        }, ...
       ];
       
       
       goToCityPage(c) {

    this.navCtrl.push(CityViewPage, {
      'name': c.name,
      'shortName': c.shortName,
      'events': c.events,
      'news': c.news,
      'weather': c.weather,
      'crimeAlert': c.crimeAlert,
      'crimeAlertTitle': c.crimeAlertTitle,
      'crimeAlertBody': c.crimeAlertBody,
      'newsItems': c.newsItems,
      'newsItemsName': c.newsItems.name,
      'newsItemsBody': c.newsItems.body,
      'newsItemsImaged': c.newsItems.imaged,
      'newsItemsImage': c.newsItems.image,
      'eventItems': c.eventItems,
      'eventItemsName': c.eventItems.name,
      'eventItemsBody': c.eventItems.body,
      'eventItemsImage': c.eventItems.image,
      'eventItemsImaged': c.eventItems.imaged
    });

  }
        
        ______________________________________________________
        
        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.city = this.navParams.get('name');
    this.cityShort = this.navParams.get('shortName');
    this.events = this.navParams.get('events');
    this.news = this.navParams.get('news');
    this.weather = this.navParams.get('weather');
    this.crimeAlert =  this.navParams.get('crimeAlert');
    this.crimeAlertTitle =  this.navParams.get('crimeAlertTitle');
    this.crimeAlertBody =  this.navParams.get('crimeAlertBody');
    this.newsItemsName =  this.navParams.get('newsItemsName');
    this.newsItemsBody =  this.navParams.get('newsItemsBody');
    this.newsItemsImaged =  this.navParams.get('newsItemsImaged');
    this.newsItemsImage =  this.navParams.get('newsItemsImage');
    this.eventItemsName =  this.navParams.get('eventItemsName');
    this.eventItemsBody =  this.navParams.get('eventItemsBody');
    this.eventItemsImaged =  this.navParams.get('eventItemsImaged');
    this.eventItemsImage =  this.navParams.get('eventItemsImage');

    this.newsEvents = [
      {
        pageTitle: 'Recent News',
        name: this.city,
        itemName: this.newsItemsName,
        imaged: this.newsItemsImaged,
        image: this.newsItemsImage,
        body: this.newsItemsBody
      },
      {
        pageTitle: 'New Events',
        name: this.city,
        itemName: this.eventItemsName,
        imaged: this.eventItemsImaged,
        image: this.eventItemsImage,
        body: this.eventItemsBody
      }
    ]
  }
```

There are more arrays like it. I'm grabbing the data that is not related to the internal array fine. However I'm having issues pulling the data from the "sub arrays" (ie newsItems and eventItems)

The low down of the project is a home page that only displays the names of cities in blocks (ie the name part of the array). --> When tapped on, it goes to a sub page that has that city and information about it (ie shortName, # of events, # of news, weather, crimeAlert(<- if this is n, it doesn't show on the dom), crimeAlertTitle, crimeAlertBody). At the bottom of that subpage it has two options "Recent News" and "New Events". --> When tapped on, it goes into a sub page of the city information sub page and it has the designated title (ie Recent News or New Events) and shows the city name under it. My issue is that on this page I can't get newsItems or eventItems to show up on this page. Especially because there can be more than one and I can't figure out where *ngFor fits into all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that accessing a property that is an array within an object doesn't work well with *ngFor... What I've done to get around this is make a function in your .ts file that returns the array... So instead of doing something like this:
.ts file:

```
getNewsItems(index: number) {
   return this.cities[i].newsItems as any[]; // 'as any[]' might not be needed
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let city of cities; index as i;">
    <div *ngFor="let newsItem of getNewsItems(i)">{{newsItem.body}}</div>
</div>
```